# How to use wildcard as the type of local variable in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

It says in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html), that

> ...wildcard, represents an unknown type. The wildcard can be used ... as the type of a ... local variable

From my point of view, this means I can write something like

```
int a;
? b;
```

but I can't.

Is it really possible?

Comment: It looks like the Java Tutorial writers did a very poor choice of words. I am sure they meant something else, because what they wrote makes no sense and it is not possible.

Comment: It is *technically* possible to use the java `Object` class as a wildcard since it can theoretically be cast to anything. BUT, this is terrible practice and should not be done unless you have a very specific reason to.

Comment: Given the context (the documentation is albout generics and the text start as "In generic code..."), I don't see anything wrong with the documentation.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula The documentation says "The wildcard can be used in a variety of situations: as the type of a parameter, field, or local variable". Do you know how to use a wildcard like `?` as a local variable or as a parameter in a method?. It is true it can only be used in generics, and therefore it can be used as a generic type argument, but that's not what they wrote.

Comment: This is a wildcard as a local variable: `List<?> a;`. And this is a wildcard as a parameter in a method: `method(List<?> parameter)`.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula As I originally said, the problem for me is in the poor choice words. You jumped to the conclusion that your examples is what they meant, some thought they meant something like `? a`. For me it should have said that you can use _a wildcard as a generic type argument_ in local variables, parameters, etc. That would disambiguate the interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an appallingly worded statement, and I'm surprised to see it in the documentation. You can't use a wildcard **as** the type of a variable, but you can use a wildcard **in** the type of a variable.

```
? a;       // no
List<?> b; // yes
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the documentation for generics. Java is strongly typed, and will not accept a wildcard as a variable type.

Wildcards will only be accepted in generic types like these:

```
List<?> x = new ArrayList<>()
```

or

```
List<? extends String> x = new ArrayList<>()
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not possible. Java is strongly typed, the `?` is used in a variety of cases (mostly to do with generics) when you can't know the type ahead of time.

I would suggest you read the rest of the documentation you posted, it has some excellent examples as to how to use `?`.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing what purpose the [unbounded wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/unboundedWildcards.html) has.  In general, it implies that you either *do not know* or *do not care about* the type when dealing with various things, such as collections.

For example, a `List<?> simpleList` is a list that contains an unknown type.

In general, `? extends Object`, so if you ever really think you need `?`, you'd want to use `Object` instead.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible, the Java Tutorial reefers that you can define a local variable using a wildcard like this:

```
List <?> localVariable;
```

but not like this:

`? localVariable;`

A wildcard is used exclusivity in Java only in Generic brackets, replacing a Type Parameter.